# Jar get image as resource

Tags: java, jar, resources, embedded-resource

I'm trying to get load an image from my jar. But no matter what string I supply for getResource() it always returns null.

```
try {
    System.out.println(Bootstrapper.class.getResource("./img/logo.png").toURI().getPath());
} catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CrawlerFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


   }
   ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(Bootstrapper.class.getResource("./img/logo.png"));
   setIconImage(ii.getImage());
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at net.sharpcode.crawler.ui.CrawlerFrame.init(CrawlerFrame.java:35)
>           at net.sharpcode.crawler.ui.CrawlerFrame.(CrawlerFrame.java:28)
>           at net.sharpcode.crawler.Bootstrapper$1.run(Bootstrapper.java:55)

[image]

I've tried:

```
getResource("") 
getResource(".") 
getResource("./") 
getResource("/img/logo.png") 
Bootstrapper.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Comment: What's the package name of your `Bootstrapper` class?

Comment: You need to show us the structure of your jar file.

Comment: @JonSkeet added a picture of the structure.

Comment: `Bootstrapper.class..` Try `this.getClass()` instead, with the path `"/img/logo.png"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.getClass().getResource("/net/sharpcode/crawler/img/logo.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the "./" part - just use:

```
Bootstrapper.class.getResource("img/logo.png");
```

... that's if it's *relative* to `Bootstrapper.class`. If the `img` "directory" is in the root of the jar file, use

```
Bootstrapper.class.getResource("/img/logo.png");
```

Comment: it just returns "null" when using "img/logo.png"

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I see the `Bootstrapper` class lies in `net.sharpcode.crawler` package. It means the following path `./img/logo.png` will be resolved to `/net/sharpcode/crawler/img/logo.png`. I guess `/img` is a top level directory, so either use absolute path:

```
Bootstrapper.class.getResource("/img/logo.png")
```

or load via `ClassLoader`:

```
Bootstrapper.class.getClassLoader().getResource("img/logo.png")
```